# add animated gif to background image in imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm trying to add an animated gif with transparency to a simple jpeg background image using imagemagick, I'm a novice when it comes to imagemagick, and command line stuff is greek to me. This is what I have mostly an amalgam of different solutions i've tried from the web.

```
 $fname = 'tmp_'.uniqid();

 //exec('convert testgif.gif -coalesce -trim \ -set dispose previous testgif.gif');
 exec("convert ".$fname.".jpg \( testgif.gif \) \ -set dispose previous -gravity Center -layers Composite \-layers Optimize -loop 0 ".$fname.".gif");
```

I also tried the simpler format of

```
exec("convert bunny_grass.gif bunny_anim.gif -loop 0  bunny_on_grass.gif");
```

I am using this as a reference http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/

The result [here](http://digital.nwedev.com/projects/nick/hnc/beta/tmp_54b04b370bc7f.gif)

Edit: I found a solution, I don't know if its the best way, but its working if anyone has an easier cleaner method, I'm all ears.

```
  exec('convert testgif.gif -coalesce -trim \ -set dispose background \ -gravity Center   -layers Composite \
      -layers Optimize cleared_testgif.gif');
  exec("convert ".$fname.".jpg \(cleared_testgif.gif -repage \)-loop 0 ".$fname.".gif");
```

Comment: Does the converting work? If no, then probably it's not a php issue, you should remove the tag. If it works then it's very unclear what your question is.

Comment: Yes, I created a link to an image, its merging but where ever the gif is transparent its erasing the background image. However I found a solution that works.